# How do I pass level 6 in chapter 4?

Tags: the-turing-test

I've figured out how to get past the first door, but once I get in I don't have any power sources with me to open the next one. I've tried re-arranging things at the first door over and over again, but every configuration that works requires all available power sources. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoiler-light hint:

> Look for residual power in one of the wires after a power source shuts off.

Spoilerific walk-through:

> First, arrange the power orbs correctly so that the first door stays open.
>  From top to bottom: Green, Purple, Blue.
>
>  Next, get as close as you can to the first door while still being in range to pull out the power orbs.
>  When the green orb turns on, quickly grab the purple one and go through the door.
>  There should be just enough charge left in the wire for you to get through before the door closes.
>
>  Use the purple orb to progress through the next door.